# How to get my process id from a pipe?

Tags: bash

Hi please forgive me if this looks totally disgusting I've just started learning how to script.

I want to kill vlc after 65 seconds whatever happens, but if it disconnects from
the source during that time I want to kill it and restart it with a new output file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

function record {
  DATE=$(date "+%d%m%y%H%M%S%N");

  cvlc -vR rtsp://192.168.1.233 \
      --sout=file/mov:/var/www/continuous/%1/$DATE.mov 2>& 1 |

  while read event;
  do
    PID=$!
    lastevent=${event#*]}
    if [ "$lastevent" == "live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?" ];
    then
      kill $PID
      record
    fi
  done
}

record &
sleep 65
kill $PID
```

The trouble is $! doesnt get the correct pid so I can't kill it. I need to get the pid of vlc.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with `$!` is wrong. It is much better to use `pkill -P$$` here.

Example:

```
cvlc -vR rtsp://192.168.1.233 \
    --sout=file/mov:/var/www/continuous/%1/$DATE.mov | while read event; do
  lastevent=${event#*]}
  if [ "$lastevent" == "live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?" ];
  then
    pkill -P$$ cvlc
  fi
done
```

Using `pkill -P$$ cvlc` you will kill that `cvlc` that was started by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

`$!` only works with processes that are put in the background *explicitly*.

The syntax as presented here would almost work in ksh, where `|&` has a different meaning:
it puts a command in the background as a co-process, which implies that you can `read` from
the co-process with `read -p event`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write the output of `cvlc` to a named pipe, then kick it to the background so you can get the pid using `$!`.  You then read from the named pipe and `cvlc` gets killed when your time limit is up.

```
# create the named pipe
MYPIPE=/tmp/cvlc_pipe_$$
rm -f ${MYPIPE} # remove the named pipe in case it already exist
mkfifo ${MYPIPE}

function record {
  DATE=$(date "+%d%m%y%H%M%S%N");

  # have cvlc write to the named pipe in the background, then get its pipe with $1
  cvlc -vR rtsp://192.168.1.233 \
      --sout=file/mov:/var/www/continuous/%1/$DATE.mov > ${MYPIPE} 2>& 1 &&
  PID=$!

  # read cvlc's output from the named pipe
  exec 7<>${MYPIPE}
  while read -u 7 event;
  do  
    PID=$!
    lastevent=${event#*]}
    if [ "$lastevent" == "live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?" ];
    then
      kill $PID
      record
    fi  
  done
  exec 7>&-
}

record &
sleep 65
kill $PID
rm -f ${MYPIPE} # cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used the end (the name of this script is vlcrecorder).

It gets the pid of its own children (pgrep), since the function calls itself it has to loop through child, grandchild, great grandchild etc 'til it finds the pid of vlc at the bottom of the tree.

Thankyou to aLL who helped me.

```
#!/bin/bash
function record {
DATE=$(date "+%d%m%y%H%M%S%N");
cvlc -v -R rtsp://$1/$2 --sout=file/mov:/var/www/continuous/2/$DATE.mov |&
while read event;
do
lastevent=${event#*]}
echo $lastevent
if [[ "$lastevent" == *"live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?"* ]]; then
sleep .1
ppid=$(pgrep -P $$ -x vlcrecorder)
vlcpid=$(pgrep -P $ppid -x vlc)
until [ -z "$ppid" ]; do
vlcppid=$vlcgppid
vlcgppid=$ppid
ppid=$(pgrep -P $ppid -x vlcrecorder)
done
vlcpid=$(pgrep -P $vlcppid -x vlc)
kill $vlcpid
record $1 $2 
fi
done
}

record $1 $2 &
sleep 65
parentpid=$!
until [ -z "$parentpid" ]; do
gppid=$parentpid
parentpid=$(pgrep -P $parentpid -x vlcrecorder)
lastvlcpid=$(pgrep -P $gppid -x vlc)
if [ -n "$lastvlcpid" ]; then
kill $lastvlcpid
fi
done
```